# Writing a file to text with BufferedWriter(Writes something strange)Java

Tags: java, eclipse, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I try to write some integers to a text file with entering only one value to each line so I used BufferedWriter.

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                          new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"), "utf-8"))) {
    writer.write(board.Player1.money);             
    writer.newLine();
    //Continues to do this for 4 players.
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write(board.Player1.position);
    writer.newLine();
    //Continues to do this for 4 players.
}
```

What I expected to see was integers in my text file. And values like `board.Player1.money` are correct because they are working for the other parts of the code. So I expect to see a value like 300 but I see the following lines in a text file.

```
Ǵ
ಀ
ಀ
ಀ
```

Why is that?

Comment: Also, you can use StandardCharsets which defines constants for `Charset` including `UTF_8`.

`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `write(...)` method of the `BufferedWriter` is overloaded.

For example: there is the method `void write(String arg)` which writes the given String to the file and there is `void write(int arg)` which converts the given Integer to a character and then writes the character to the file.

To solve your propblem you'll have to change

```
writer.write(board.Player1.position);
```

to

```
writer.write(Integer.toString(board.Player1.position));
```

Comment: This solution is ok,but  I have a question.When I save it as a string,it will still write an integer value(in real life) to file.So when I try to read it back can I directly put it into an integer array or I should use Integer.parseInt after reading the file?

Comment: When you read it back you'll have to use some `readLine()` method. The resulting String will have to be parsed to Integer using `Integer.parseInt(...)`!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is:

```
writer.write(board.Player1.money+"");
```

Comment: I was writing that at the same time with you(swh)..But also in this situation we should  use Integer.parseInt.I tested this and it behaved in a correct way

Answer (score 1):

write(int c) with integer is expecting a character.
Consider using write(String s, int off, int len), or some wrapper like PrintWriter

Comment: This solution seems ok if someone has the same problem they can use it but I only want to save one int value in each line.For my purpose,I think writing Integer.toString is better but this answer is also valid.